# Get Pagination (WP-PageNavi) not to work

Tags: loop, pagination, page-template

I have several problems to get the pagination work.

I have a custom page template, in there i need to display all blog posts. I build up the following "query" and build up my html structure:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 5,
    'paged'             => $paged,
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( ! empty( $posts ) && ! is_wp_error( $posts )) {
   $displaylist = '<div class="list-group">';

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        /* loop stuff */
    }

    $displaylist .= '</div>';

    echo( $displaylist );
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'type' => 'multipart' ) );
}
```

with this i get the posts as i expected but not the pagination controls.

Please note: it's not the "main" page, it's a sub page.

After research i notice many use this:

```
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

instead of this:

```
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

if i use the `WP_Query($args)` i get many empty posts while i have only 3 posts.

I have no idea what i do wrong but I'm a absolutely newbie to wordpress and php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of issues here;

- Don't use `get_posts` for paginated queries. It legally breaks/ignore pagination as it passes `no_found_rows=true` to `WP_Query`. Further more, `get_posts` only returns the `$posts` property from the query object, and pagination needs other properties from the query object to calculate pagination. You can paginate `get_posts`, but it is a really messy affair, and get_posts`is just a wrapper function for`WP_Query`.
- Do not use the global `$posts` variable (*or any other global variable in Wordpress or PHP*) as a custom variable. This breaks the global variables as you are assigning different content to the variable. This is the most likely issue that is causing the inconsistent results from your query with `WP_Query`. Always use custom variables. The only exception to this is when you are using `setup_postdata( $post )` with `get_posts` or similar functions, `setup_postdata()` requires the use of the `$post` global. Here you need to remember to use `wp_reset_postdata()` after you are done to restore the `$post` global
- When using `get_posts`, you don't need the check for a `WP_Error` object as `get_posts` only return an array of posts or an empty array. It will never return a `WP_Error` object

You should try the following:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 5,
    'paged'             => $paged,
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args ),

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {

    $displaylist = '<div class="list-group">';

    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        // LOOP STUFF HERE

    } // endwhile

    $displaylist .= '</div>';

    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $q ) );

    wp_reset_postdata(); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT

} // endif
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now the `new WP_Query($args)` produce no errors but the pagination is still not working.

Comment: O crap, sorry, I forgot the pagination part, will update the code ;-)

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy ;-)